# Typescript function accepting invalid argument with no error

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to understand the extent of the typesafety offered by Typescript.  I've come across a scenario where I expect an error, but Typescript doesn't complain.

I've defined a function with a parameter matching a certain interface.  Then I call the function with some arguments which don't match.  Here's the code ([or in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=interface%20ArgumentInterface%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%5Bkey%3A%20number%5D%3A%20string%0A%7D%0A%0Ainterface%20InvalidArgumentInterface%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%5Bkey%3A%20string%5D%3A%20number%0A%7D%0A%0Ainterface%20InvalidArgumentInterface2%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20foo%3A%20number%0A%7D%0A%0Afunction%20myFunction(arg%3A%20ArgumentInterface)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20function%20body%0A%7D%0A%0Alet%20validArgument%3A%20ArgumentInterface%20%3D%20%7B%7D%3B%0AvalidArgument%5B5%5D%20%3D%20'I%20am%20a%20string'%3B%0A%0Alet%20invalidArgument%3A%20InvalidArgumentInterface%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20foo%3A%2042%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Alet%20invalidArgument2%3A%20%7Bfoo%3A%20number%7D%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20foo%3A%2042%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Alet%20invalidArgument3%3A%20InvalidArgumentInterface2%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20foo%3A%2042%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Alet%20invalidArgument4%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20foo%3A%2042%0A%7D%3B%0A%0AmyFunction(validArgument)%3B%20%2F%2F%20no%20typescript%20error%2C%20as%20expected%0AmyFunction(invalidArgument)%3B%20%2F%2F%20typescript%20error%2C%20as%20expected%0AmyFunction(invalidArgument2)%3B%20%2F%2F%20no%20typescript%20error!%0AmyFunction(invalidArgument3)%3B%20%2F%2F%20typescript%20error%2C%20as%20expected%0AmyFunction(invalidArgument4)%3B%20%2F%2F%20no%20typescript%20error!)):

```
interface ArgumentInterface {
    [key: number]: string
}

interface InvalidArgumentInterface {
    [key: string]: number
}

interface InvalidArgumentInterface2 {
    foo: number
}

function myFunction(arg: ArgumentInterface) {
    // function body
}

let validArgument: ArgumentInterface = {};
validArgument[5] = 'I am a string';

let invalidArgument: InvalidArgumentInterface = {
    foo: 42
};

let invalidArgument2: {foo: number} = {
    foo: 42
};

let invalidArgument3: InvalidArgumentInterface2 = {
    foo: 42
};

let invalidArgument4 = {
    foo: 42
};

myFunction(validArgument); // no typescript error, as expected
myFunction(invalidArgument); // typescript error, as expected
myFunction(invalidArgument2); // no typescript error!
myFunction(invalidArgument3); // typescript error, as expected
myFunction(invalidArgument4); // no typescript error!
```

When my argument variable explicitly declares an incompatible interface, I get a Typescript error as expected.  But when my argument variable declares a type literal (without an interface) or declares no type at all, Typescript doesn't complain at all, although I'd expect an error.

I have the "noImplicitAny" flag set to true.

Can anybody explain this behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not getting an error for:

```
myFunction(invalidArgument2);
myFunction(invalidArgument4);
```

Because their type is `{ foo: number; }` and it doesn't contradict the definition of `ArgumentInterface`, a value can be both:

```
let a = {
    1: "one",
    2: "two",
    foo: 4
}
```

Here what's indexed with a number has a string value, but the foo index has a number value.

if `ArgumentInterface` is:

```
interface ArgumentInterface {
    [key: number]: string;
    [key: string]: string;
}
```

Then you get the errors where you expected them.

Comment: I think I've discovered what I misunderstood: defining an index signature for [key: number] doesn't prevent adding string keys, it only restricts the value type **if the key is a number** ?  Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that seems the case. But it doesn't work the other way around. Also, you should be aware that key in a js object are **always** strings. If you pass a number it will be converted into a string. If you really want a map between number and strings use a `Map`

Answer (score 1):

This is because [TypeScript uses structural typing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html) (like Ocaml).

`invalidArgument2` and `invalidArgument4` are both structurally compatible to `ArgumentInterface`, and as such, TypeScript happily accepts them.

Comment: No, they are not equivalent.  `ArgumentInterface` is of type `{ [k: number]: string }` while the other two are of type `{ foo: number }`. Those are different structures.

Comment: replaced the word with "compatible", which is used in the docs I link to.

Comment: Well, compatible makes more sense. Though, I'd say that there are no conflicts between the two.